# Java Swing: jpanel not fitting content when have scrollbar/list

Tags: java, swing

[image]

I have a file with a JScrollBar and a JPanel inside with boxlayout.

In another file I have a JPanel (also BoxLayout) with a JList inside (without JScrollPane - only the list). The list can grow as much as it needs.

The problem is when I add the 2nd file in the first file JPanel, it just does not resize to fit the content. The JList is just cutted like the next image.

[image]

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art of the GUI as it should appear in smallest size and (if resizable) with extra width/height.

Comment: I have only the netbeans project, I'll try to make it clean.

Comment: Ok, I think I solved it already.

Thanks to answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815401/how-do-i-recalculate-preferred-size-of-a-jcomponent

I've used 

    component.setPreferredSize(null);

to recalculate the preferredSize of the jList and all of its parents at the 2nd file. It was enough for me.

Comment: `used component.setPreferredSize(null);`  Ah yes.  Twice a day, three times on some days, we get questions here where ***not*** doing that is the solution.  Glad you got it sorted.  :)  You should consider now either deleting the question, or entering your own answer.

Comment: I can only answer after 8 hours.
I will post the answer later because I did not find anything similar on net, it might be helpfull for someone.

Thanks!

Comment: By the way it seems to me that you are mixing up `JScrollBar` and `JScrollPane` in your question.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, the image says "bar", but it should be pane!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[posting as an answer]

Ok, I think I solved it already.

Thanks to answer of this question: [How do i recalculate preferred size of a JComponent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815401/how-do-i-recalculate-preferred-size-of-a-jcomponent)

I've used

```
component.setPreferredSize(null);
```

to recalculate the preferredSize of the jList and all of its parents at the 2nd file. It was enough to solve for me.